# Загрузка изображения ajax

Tags: ajax, php, изображения

Здравствуйте, появился такой вопрос, точнее не выходит реализовать.
есть простая форма

```
<form action="/do/sm.php" method="post" name="form">
<textarea class="form_texparea" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="send">
</form>
```

в голове обработка отправление получение

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(){
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var idnews = $("#idnews").val();
        var loads = $("#uploadImage").val();                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/do/sm.php",
            data: {"message": message,"id": id,"idnews": idnews,"loads": loads},
            cache: false,                       
            success: function(response){
                var messageResp = new Array('Успешно','Ошибка','Нельзя отправлять пустые сообщения'); 
                    rel_q();$("#message").val("");
                var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
                $("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);    
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

и запись php о загрузке изображения в папочку

```
$extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
$max_size = 500000;
$path = 'uploads/comments/';
$response = '';
if ($_FILES['uploadImage'] != '')
{
  if ($_FILES['uploadImage']['size'] > $max_size)
  {
    $response = 'File is too large';
  }
  else
  {
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['uploadImage']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $extensions))
    {
      $path = $path . uniqid() . '.' . $ext;

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name'], $path))
      {
        $response = "<img style='height: 100px' src='$path' />";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $response = 'File must be an image!';
    }
  }
}
```

комментарий отправляется, картинка не загружается, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Deonis, возник вопрос по поводу той статейки, куда выводится результат? все установил, по идее вообще ничего не происходит, как и должно открывается php файл, по суди дела js вообще не используется в примере

Comment: @singmen, почему-то я не удивлён. В общем, сделал за вас. [Скачиваете архив][1], распаковываете в корень сайта, т.к. пути прописаны из расчета на это или же изменяете пути на свои. И на всякий случай - проверил, работает.

Кстати, я не зря спрашивал вас о том, работает ли вообще скрипт, потому что имя поля файла у вас "image", а ловите вы его с ключом "uploadImage". И последнее... Специально засёк время на всю эту работу. Отбрасывая секунды, получилось 4 минуты. Это время на то, что бы скопипастить ваш код, изменить пути и исправить пару самых грубых ошибок.

   [1]:http://rghost.ru/57437885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[[[[[@singmen](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen), иногда ощущение, что у меня дежавю )) Буквально вчера этот вопрос задавал другой человек. Не могу найти, поэтому повторю. Есть несколько способов выйти из ситуации:

1. Использовать готовые плагины
2. Отправлять данные через iframe (но это уже имитация ajax-запроса)
3. А если хотите именно Ajax и без сторонних плагинов, то [почитайте эту статейку](http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-zagruzka-fajlov.html).

**Обновление**

[[[[[[@singmen](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen), по ссылке, которую я показал вам выше, можно скачать пример. Вам только остается изменить обработчик на свой. Кстати, для начала, вы бы протестировали свой код в обычном режиме и убедились в том, что файлы загружаются и туда, куда вы планировали.

**Обновление 2**

[[[[[[@singmen](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen)](/users/22330/singmen), тогда проблем не должно возникнуть. Скачали пример, изменили поля формы на свои, изменили селекторы (классы, id), записали свой обработчик. Или вы не верите, что всё так просто и хотите, чтоб кто-то это за вас сделал?

Comment: @Deonis, статейку подобную видел и попытался встроить уже в свое, но не вышло

Comment: @singmen, что именно не получается?

Comment: @Deonis, добавление комментария идет т.е. код верный, а загрузка изображения не происходит

Comment: @Deonis, код да, тестировали, изображение загружалось отлично туда, куда нужно

Comment: @Deonis, хорошо, днем попытаюсь переделать пример и если вопросы возникнут подниму пост. спасибо.